# Page not displaying, error not shown in console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been informed of a JS bug error on the below link, but nothing is showing in the console? The issue appears to be occurring only in Chrome, and although the DOM appears to be loading in the page content and structure, it is unable to display it. Can anybody offer any advice as to why this might be happening, or how to debug errors that don't appear in the console?

I am now questioning if this is indeed a script issue, or perhaps CSS/HTML related instead? The ocntent appears to be loading, but behind the #sidebar.

Any help appreciated to debug this issue!

[Link](http://www.iamjim.co.uk/)

Comment: It does have a error: SVG's SMIL animations (<animate>, <set>, etc.) are deprecated and will be removed. Please use CSS animations or Web animations instead.

Comment: I don't know how your `<figure>` elements are placed, but it could come from missing CSS attributes on the container or bad placing script.

Comment: @Dirk-Jan deprecation messages are not an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also got the SMIL animations error, but I don't think that's the problem. The problem is that the body has a fixed width and it doesn't span the entire page. This happens because the only content it's getting as childs is the sidenav (the content has position relative, which removes it from the DOM structure), and this page probably uses bootstrap, which removes the default html and body width of 100% for some reason.

If you add a `width: 100%` to the body in CSS, you can see the content again. It's positioned to the far right of the window, but I don't know if that's an error or not.

Comment: Hi @groooves. That is brilliant, thank you so much for your help. Oddly, the site was developed in Chrome (approx 3 months ago), so it must be related to an update to the browser. Thanks again, and yes, the content should be right aligned :)

Comment: Glad I could help. =)